# i have a procedure with a parameter, parameter must be default nothing, but i want to make a if parameter = name_procedure exec procedure else nothing

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure1(l_nothing varchar2)
as
begin
if l_nothing := procedure_2 then
exec procedure_2(2);
else l_nothing := NULL
dbms.output_put_line(l_nothing);
end if;
end;
/

create or replace procedure2(l_id in varchar2)
return NUMBER is l_name NUMBER(9);
begin
select name into l_name from test where  l_id =id;
return  l_name;
end;
/
```

it's possible to make o procedure to execute another procedure with if statment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure1(l_nothing varchar2)
as
begin
    if lower(l_nothing) = 'procedure2' then
      procedure2(2);
    else 
      dbms.output_put_line(l_nothing);
    end if;
end;
```

Procedure doesn't return any value.. so, you need to either change procedure2 to function or create a out parameter in procedure2